# iOS Opening a stand alone navigation controller as modal

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to open a navigation controller as model but in full screen mode. So let me start with some details

**What I Want:**  I want following thing

1. From MainVC I want to show a new view controller (DetailsVC) but as
   a modally presented VC but that must be shown with Navigation
   controller
2. That modally presented VC must be full screen in all OS versions

**What I have done:** I have embedded The new ViewController  (DetailsVC) into Navigation controller and trying to open it from MainVC as modally as following

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "idDetailsVC") as! DetailsVC
    
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    let navigationVc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    self.present(navigationVc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

it shows navigation controller modally but it is not full screen on OS 13 however if I try following code it shows full Screen ViewController but there is no Navigation Controller.

```
        let detailsVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "idDetailsVC") as! DetailsVC
    detailsVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    detailsVC.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve


    self.present(detailsVC, animated: true, completion: {

    })
```

> **So there are mainly 3 things I want**

1. I want to open a ViewController (DetailsVC) which is embedded in NavigationController
2. I want to show that (DetailsVC) as modally
3. I want to show back button at very first view controller ((DetailsVC))

> **Update:** I can not put ManVC into Navigation controller for some reason.The reason is that for a reference I have told this the MainVC is being used to open the DetailVC but the truth is the DetailsVC is a controller that can be opened by many other viewController and some of those does not have navigation controller as a root. So I decided to add the navigation controller on the DetailsVC. Hope that helps ...

Comment: Why can’t you put main VC in a navigation controller?

Comment: If your problem is with NavigationBar in MainVC there are workarounds to hide it, Is there any other reasons you dont want to embed it in Navigation Controller?

Comment: @Matt Y cant I? this discussion will not put the solution of the problem

Comment: @MohyG I have already embedded the DetailVC into navigation controller. but due to some reasons I can not put my mainVC into Navigation controller. You can think I have it to do as it is.

The reason is updated in question

Comment: @Matt the reason is also updated in question....

Comment: You can embed all the other view controllers in navigation controllers.  Are you sure you can’t just have a done button or something and present modally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one problem with your code. You set the controller property to show it on full screen but you are presenting the navigation controller. You need to the set the property of the navigation controller as the full screen.

```
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

if let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "idDetailsVC") as? DetailsVC{

let navigationVc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
navigationVc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(navigationVc, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

You can add a custom button in the navigation controller now. But remember you can't pop as the DetailsVC is the rootViewController of the navigation Controller's stack. Since it was presented, you can dissolve the navigation controller, and the presenting view controller will show. However you have to use a custom action.

Also it's not a good idea to force cast.

To create your back button, create a UIBarButtonItem and add to the left bar item like this.

```
func setupNavigationBar(){
  let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(backButtonPressed))
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
}

@objc func backButtonPressed(){
  self.navigationController?.dismiss(.default)
}
```

The backButton is custom created with title. You can initialize barbuttonitem with image as well. I am not sure if the system has one itself or not. So I hope you get the gist of it.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer. Can you tell me how to dissolve?

Comment: Add this in your custom action. You need to dissolve the navigationController as a whole in your DetailVC. self.navigationController?.dismiss(.default)

Comment: good, one thing remaining and that is back button on the DetailVC